# Word division in properties/labels of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to make a word division with long labels in QGIS properties of a vector layer?

For example:
Name of the label: **Llanfairpwllgwyngyll**

Should be labelled:

```
Llanfair-
pwllgwyn-           
gyll
```

After every hyphen a new row starts.

Answer (score 4):

`regexp_replace` in the expression dialog (click on red circle below in the Label tab of the Layer Styling panel) might do the trick without much complexity.

[image]

If you tell us exactly what rules you want the label to wrap with (e.g. after every 8 characters, after spaces, not including hyphens, etc.), perhaps someone could give you an elegant expression that would do exactly what you want.

**A crude, simple demonstration**:

```
regexp_replace("label",'(\\w{X}\\B)',concat('\\1','-','\n'))
```

will...

- take your input string (the field "label")
- capture every **X** number of consecutive word characters (`\\w{X}`)
- *excluding* word boundary characters (spaces, dashes, etc...) (`\\B`)
- and add a dash (`'-'`) and linebreak (`\n`) after each captured group (`\\1`) - but not at the

So for your example where it wraps after **8** consecutive word characters

```
regexp_replace("cymru_town",'(\\w{8}\\B)',concat('\\1','-','\n'))
```

will get you...

```
Llanfair-
pwllgwyn-
gyll

Aberystw-
yth

Buith Wells

Hay-On-Wye

Llanfair-
pwllgwyn-
gyll township

Swansea township and surround-
s
```

as you can see with the last example, once you have word boundary characters (e.g. spaces) it restarts the character count, so here it only breaks after it finds 'surround' (8 consecutive word characters), which isn't ideal.

With the right regexp expression you can account for these situations too.

If you are new to regex, try a basic tutorial like https://regexone.com/